# Eevee в blender 2.8 рендерит изображение на CPU вместо GPU

Tags: cuda, blender, render

Характеристики: Nvidia GeForce GTX 980, IntelCore i5-6500 CPU 3.20 GHz, ubuntu 16.04, blender 2.8, в настройках preferences - CUDA выбрана.
При использовании движка eevee картинка вместо GPU рендерится на CPU(очень медленно) и даже при работе на несложной сцене подтормаживает... Для проверки работы GPU использую nvidia-smi(проверял и при рендеринге и просто при работе на сцене):
Processes:                                                   GPU Memory
GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage 
0      2975      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          88MiB.

Если для этой же сцены ставлю движок cycles(device - GPU Compute) сцена при работе на ней не тормозит, а вполне адекватно работает(GPU работает отлично). nvidia-smi:
Processes:                                                     GPU Memory 
GPU       PID   Type   Process name                          Usage
0        2975      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                     88MiB
0        8908      C   /snap/blender/33/./blender             668MiB.

Подскажите, почему так происходит?
Согласно документации blender 2.8 eevee должна работать на GPU...

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://developer.blender.org/rB663d23dd9dc4801a679b00e5d8ac80483d9b36a8), вроде были недавно исправления похожего бага.

Попробуй [последнюю](https://builder.blender.org/download/) сборку.

Кстати, настройки *CUDA* (насколько понимаю) относятся только к *Cycles*.